# Angular 6, How to get the target element for an 'onSelectionChange' dom event?

Tags: angular, typescript

Using angular 6, whenever the selection changes I want to get the "formControlName" of the corresponding element.

**HTML**

```
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="dispatchAdviceChildForAdd._isEditMode" class="mat-form-field-fluid">
        <mat-select placeholder="Select Product" formControlName="newProductCode" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let pl of productList" value="{{pl.productCode}}" (onSelectionChange)="changeValues($event,pl)">{{pl.productCode}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
        <mat-hint align="start">
            <strong>Select</strong>
        </mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**TYPESCRIPT "changeValues"**

```
 changeValues(event, data: ProductListModel) {
      // here i need formControlName
 }
```

I have tried the following ways but no help:

```
 changed(event) {
   console.log(event.target.id); 
 }
```

I have also tried

```
changed(event) {
 const target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
 const idAttr = target.attributes.id;
 const value = idAttr.nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: please add html and your form control

Comment: missed it, check now

Comment: logging gives "undefined"

Comment: `onSelectionChange` property represents the event handler that is called when a `selectionChange` event reaches this object. In my case user chooses another option from the select

Comment: there is an event, you can check here, [onSelectionChange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/onselectionchange)

Comment: You should use `change` instead of `onSelectionChange`, that is not supported well in browsers and is experimental at the moment.

Comment: Okay, thanks Yousaf for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Am i missing something, but why don't you just provide it like this:

```js
changeValues(event, data: ProductListModel, controlName: string) {
      // here i need formControlName
 }
```

```html
<mat-form-field *ngIf="dispatchAdviceChildForAdd._isEditMode" class="mat-form-field-fluid">
    <mat-select placeholder="Select Product" formControlName="newProductCode" required>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let pl of productList" value="{{pl.productCode}}" (onSelectionChange)="changeValues($event,pl,'newProductCode')">{{pl.productCode}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-hint align="start">
        <strong>Select</strong>
    </mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

To get reference to the component itself, you can use:

```js
changeValues(event, something, matComponent) {
  // not using material components so i dont know the class

}
```

```html
<mat-form-field *ngIf="dispatchAdviceChildForAdd._isEditMode" class="mat-form-field-fluid">
    <mat-select #matSelect placeholder="Select Product" formControlName="newProductCode" required>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let pl of productList" value="{{pl.productCode}}" (onSelectionChange)="changeValues($event,pl, matSelect)">{{pl.productCode}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-hint align="start">
        <strong>Select</strong>
    </mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is used template referencing with #matSelect and then providing it to callback

Comment: Thanks Ales, i see how easily this problem can be resolved. This trick of sending formControlName as an argument works.